# How to run a same command using a range of a parameter in a loop?

Tags: python, bash

I want to run this command using values from 1 to 22 after --CHROM flag, like:

```
python eigenMT.py --CHROM 1  --QTL SG.cis.eqtls.txt --GEN SG.genotypes.txt --GENPOS SG.gen.positions.txt --PHEPOS SG.phe.positions.txt --OUT SG_Out.txt
```

I tried to make a bash script looking like this:

```
for i in {1..22}
do
        python eigenMT.py --CHROM $i  --QTL SG.cis.eqtls.txt --GEN SG.genotypes.txt --GENPOS SG.gen.positions.txt --PHEPOS SG.phe.positions.txt --OUT SG_Out.txt
done
```

but I am getting an empty SG_Out.txt file.

Can you please help me how to run this over all 22 values and write output in one file?

I should mention that if I run this one by one (without loop) it works.

Comment: You probably want `--OUT SG_Out-${i}.txt`

Comment: If you put `echo ` in front of `python`, does it print 22 different command lines with the correct CHROM parameters?

Comment: @RedCricket OP wants *one* file. @anikaM If the python script prints to stdout when `--OUT file` is omitted then put `> file` after `done`.

Comment: @RedCricket Thank you!

Comment: @Socowi Thank you!

Comment: @RedCricket how do I join afterwards all SG_Out-${i}.txt files? They all have the same header and I just want to keep and header and join everything else

Comment: I guess I can just do this: head -1 SG_Out-1.txt > all.txt
tail -n +2 -q SG_Out* >> all.txt

Comment: I guess you could do, `cat SG_Out-*.txt > SG_Out.txt`.

Comment: @Red Cricket  that keeps headers from all files

Comment: bdw why did I get a negative point, what is wrong with my post?

Answer (score 0):

This probably does what you want, without creating temp files

```
for i in {1..22}
do
        python eigenMT.py --CHROM $i  --QTL SG.cis.eqtls.txt --GEN SG.genotypes.txt --GENPOS SG.gen.positions.txt --PHEPOS SG.phe.positions.txt | tail -n +2
done > SG_Out.txt
```

Comment: Hello I tried this but eigenMT.py: error: argument --OUT is required